# Prove that $b_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2}} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to prove that $b_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2}} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$

My initial thoughts are to sandwich this (seems sensible to me). Finding the above inequality $b_n < 1$ was easy, since clearly $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + k}} < \frac{1}{n}$ for integer k. But I'm stuck on how to compare it with something from below.

A hint I've been given is that if $a_n \to a$, then $\sqrt{a_n} \to \sqrt{a}$ as $n \to \infty$, though I'm struggling to see a way of applying this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see,

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ is the biggest term and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}$ is the smallest one. Doing this, we can say:

$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}<b_n<\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$

Taking the limits on both sides of the inequality, we find that

$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=1$

QED.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\leq\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: I like your integral approach! (Pun intended)

Comment: @HasanSaad Haha! That's the method that came to mind before I saw the OP approached by Squeeze theorem.

Comment: It sure did not come to my mind... (Squeeze theorem seemed more "natural" in this case...)

Comment: Everyone thinks differently. I was able to visualize the $\frac{i}{n}$ terms easily.

Comment: Yeah, I guess everyone thinks differently.

Comment: @Arpan Please, I don't understand your answer, why do you write $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2}}$ whereas $$ \sqrt{n^2+i}=n\sqrt{1+\frac{i}{n^2}}\neq\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2}$$

Comment: The $n$ is still there.

Comment: @Arpan Yes, but there is no square for $i$...

Comment: @Arpan You can observe that: $$ \int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\ln(1+\sqrt{2})\neq 1$$

Comment: @Euler'sstudent Right. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* You can check that $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n+n^{2}}}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+n^{2}}}\leq\frac{n}{\sqrt{1+n^{2}}}.$$

Comment: @HasanSaad LOL!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: which one of the summands is the smallest?